# How can you complete the guessing game achievement on PC?

Tags: achievements, payday-2

The Guessing Game achievement is for completing the following;

> **Guessing Game**
>   On day 2 of the Firestarter job, complete the heist in stealth without hacking the computer

Since the PC version of Payday 2 gets all the fancy updates which changes the way that a large number of skills work, many of the guides explaining how to complete the Guessing Game achievement no longer correctly represent the state of the game and show one person walking around the FBI building dominating all of the guards, or following the guards around at close range without alerting them.

The sort of information that I need to know is as follows;

- What sort of skillset is going to be required to complete this achievement? (I'm assuming at least the **Smooth Talker** ability and maybe a couple of people with the **Dominator** ability?)
- Where are the possible spawn points for the control boxes containing the wires that have to be cut?
- Is the wire you need to cut actually completely random or is there a particular methodology to choosing the right one?

How can you complete the guessing game achievement on PC?

Comment: The steam guide using ECMs is still very relevant. Cables to cut are random.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Helpful Preparations

- ECM with pager delay and door opening (The more pager delay you have, the better)
- As low detection risk as possible
- Dominator & Smooth talker (useful if caught *before* grabbing the server a lot to save the situation)
- Cameras
- A lot of patience

The achievement requires no alarms and no computer. You are allowed to be detected as long as no alarm goes off before in the debriefing screen.

### Completion

#### Part 1: Security Boxes

You're looking for small white boxes on the walls. You'll want to **avoid guards** and breaking cameras at all costs as there is *no way* you can take out all of the guards on the level. There are at least 7 guards every time and they seem to be replaced with new ones as you kill them off.

First off, you'll want to check the cameras to see if you can find any of the security boxes. If possible, have a friend sit on the cameras checking for guards that are coming your way at any given time. Check the outside walls and the lobby first, because they are the easiest possible locations for the boxes.

Once you have located a box, you can open it, cut the wire and **close it**. The guards will notice an open box and call an alarm.

**NOTE:** You must be standing in order to cut the wire.

This part of the mission is random. There are *three* security boxes and you need to cut *two* wires. One of the three boxes triggers the alarm. If an alarm goes off, restart the mission and try again. It can take quite a few attempts to get the correct boxes.

#### Part 2: Server room

Once you have the wires cut, the alarm for the server room door is disabled. Find the server room. The safest way to find it is to check the cameras for the door. There are four locations where it can be:

- Next to the back door
- Above the lobby, a bit on the right
- At the back wall next to the room full of computers
- At the back wall next to the glass room (meeting room)

Only one should go in and he should have his ECM upgraded to open doors. Sneak to the server room door without being seen and pick the lock **when there are no guards nearby**. Open the second door with the ECM and grab the server. Guards will notice the *second* door open and will come check it out. Sneak out as fast as possible and finish the mission.

If you get caught while carrying the server and you have a player with pager-delaying ECMs, have him chain his ECMs one after another as you run out killing all the guards you see on your way. The alarm will not go off until the ECMs run out, but the ECM **MUST HAVE PAGER DELAY**. If your ECM is *not* upgraded with that, answer the pager of the guard that caught you and then run and hope for the best.